# How to fire a button click event from a include page (visual page)

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

In my main Visualforce page I have included one header page. In the header page there several hyperlinks. Now, where I navigate from one hyperlink to other hyperlink I want to access main page's Custom button click event.

Can you provide a code snippet in apex?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but you might want to look at  and if you need to pass a parameter:  in VisualForce:

`<apex:commandLink action="{!buttonClickEventAction">
   <apex:param name="q" value="{!contact.name}"/>
</apex:commandLink>`